# How to send a NDP message?

Tags: networking, osx

I would like to send a NDP ( Neighbor Discovery Protocol ) message from my Mac on the network to discover which device is available or not.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean NDP for IPv6 as defined in [RFC 2461](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2461)?  If so, there is [`ndp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ndp.8.html) command for OSX.  To quickly get results you can run:

```
ndp -an
```